# How do i can disable cache in /wp-admin/*

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Reason, why i need disable cache:

When i create post or page. It caches its. If i create second post or page, then it updates old post or page. 
When i disabled cache for each pages, this bug was fixed. Although i need cache for SEO.

So, i need disable cache only in admin pages.

.htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|woff2)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(xml|txt)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1800, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|jpg|png|jpeg|gif|xml|json|txt|pdf|mov|avi|otf|woff|ico|swf)$">
  RequestHeader unset Cookie
  Header unset Cookie
  Header unset Set-Cookie
  </FilesMatch>


  # Guarantee HTTPS for 1 Year including Sub Domains
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;"
</ifModule>
```

function.php

```
if (is_admin()) {
      header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
      header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
      header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
}
```

My code in function.php don't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that any cache headers set in .htaccess have priority, and it is impossible to override them in PHP.

The only solution that I can think of is to disable the caching setup in the .htaccess and manually set the headers in each file. It's a pain, I know, but it's all that I can fathom.

The below answer will set caching to the browser default, which I assume is not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the .htacess

```
Header set Cache-Control “max-age=86400, public”
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove these line from the .htacess

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1800, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

You just need lines like below

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
AddType application/font-woff2 .woff2
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0
ExpiresByType video/webm A10368000
ExpiresByType video/ogg A10368000
ExpiresByType video/mp4 A10368000
ExpiresByType image/webp A10368000
ExpiresByType image/gif A10368000
ExpiresByType image/png A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A10368000
ExpiresByType image/ico A10368000
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A10368000
ExpiresByType text/css A10368000
ExpiresByType text/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A10368000
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2 A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype A10368000
ExpiresByType application/x-font-truetype A10368000
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|svg|css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```